# global variables in included php file

Tags: php, function, random, include

I have a website. On this website, I am trying to generate random images. The code for this looked messy when I had it mixed in with the rest of the HTML on the main page, so I decided to use an 'include' call to call another page with the php functions I wanted on it.
The problem with calling functions to run the specific blocks of code is, that when it runs, it doesn't recognise that I have tried to put some global variables at the top, therefore when it outputs a number, there isn't one because it never had one.

Can anybody tell me how I can fix this, so that I can use the variables so that they have the initial values I would like?

```
<?php
$total1 = "4";
$start = "1";
$random1 = mt_rand($start, $total1);
$total2 = "3";
$random2 = mt_rand($start, $total2);

function randomImage1()
{
  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  $image_name = $random1 . $file_type;
  echo ("<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"     height=\"100px\" />");
  echo("$random1");
}

function randomImage2()
{
  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  if ($random2 == $random1) {
      $random2 = $random2 + 1;
  } 
  $image_name = $random2 . $file_type;
  echo "<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"         height=\"100px\" />"; 

  echo("$random2");
}
?>
```

Comment: I read this several times and I don't understand what you are asking. If you want global variables, just use the `global` directive, e.g. `global $var;` wherever you need it in the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the variables globally inside the functions, or better yet, pass them as parameters:

```
// pass $random1 as a parameter
function randomImage1($random1)
{
  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  $image_name = $random1 . $file_type;
  echo ("<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"     height=\"100px\" />");
  echo("$random1");
}

// Pass $random2 as a parameter
function randomImage2($random2)
{
  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  if ($random2 == $random1) {
      $random2 = $random2 + 1;
  } 
  $image_name = $random2 . $file_type;
  echo "<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"         height=\"100px\" />"; 

  echo("$random2");
}
```

This could also be done with the `global` keyword inside the function, but passing parameters as above is preferred:

```
function randomImage1($random1)
{
  // Identify $random1 as the existing global
  global $random1;
  // Or use $GLOBALS['random1']

  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  $image_name = $random1 . $file_type;
  echo ("<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"     height=\"100px\" />");
  echo("$random1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in front of included file:

```
global $total1, $start, $random1, $total2, $random2;
```

This will make the following variables global even being included into a function.

Answer (score 0):

you have to either pass the variables to the functions or declare them as global in the function... I strongly recommend passing them...

```
function randomImage1($random1)
{
  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  $image_name = $random1 . $file_type;
  echo ("<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"     height=\"100px\" />");
  echo("$random1");
}
```

or this:

```
function randomImage1()
{
  global $random1;

  $file_type = ".jpg";
  $image_folder = "Images/Picturebar";
  $image_name = $random1 . $file_type;
  echo ("<img src=\"$image_folder/$image_name\" alt=\"$image_name\" width=\"204px\"     height=\"100px\" />");
  echo("$random1");
}
```

I doubt anyone here will tell you to declare the global var though. better to pass it to the function.

Comment: gee, I stand corrected. seems everyone is suggesting globals. when you declare global IN the function it keeps it within that scope and does not set it as global to everything.

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable declared outside the namespace of the function, use the `global` keyword:

```
$var = 1;

function square()
{
    global $var; // import this variable

    return $var * $var;   
}
```

Note that you should consider using function parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the value never changes use define, to define a constant such as: 
`<?php define('START', '1') ?>`

Then in your code you can call it like this:
`$start = START`

That was just an example, you can just use START you don't have to add it to another variable.